# Is there a way to make the static recource name dynamic

Tags: visualforce

I want to have a field in which I save the static resource name and dynamically show this in a visualforce page see my example if this is possible:

```
<apex:variable var="Logo" value="{!Account.Logo_Static_Recource__c }" />
<apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource[Logo])}" width="300" height=""/>
```

Comment: What does your snippet do for you? Do you get an error? Have you looked at what URL is generated (if one is)? You can see this by viewing the page source or using the Inspector/browser debugger.

Comment: @PhilW My question is if there is a way to make the part after $Resource. variable. URLFOR($Resource.staticrecourename)} works I want to know if I can make staticrecourename a variable from a field in  Salesforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is well documented by Salesforce in the [Visualforce Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_resource.htm). Fundamentally you use a controller or extension controller to provide a property that you then use in the $Resource reference.